# JQuery AJAX Autocomplete issue with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I'm having a problem with my autocomplete. It works on another one of my pages, but on this one, it doesn't work. It's returning the correct number of entries, but they are all "blank" (or at least black so I can't see it), and selecting one does not put it into the text field either.

I'm using this: http://papermashup.com/jquery-php-ajax-autosuggest/

My page right now looks like [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/brT7y.png]

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

I'd post my code, but it's pretty much exactly what's on the site linked above, with some variables changed, and embedded into a PHP. Let me know if you want to see it (I don't want to paste it here and make the page huge and fugly).

Oh and this is taking it from a column in a MySQL database.

Comment: log your sql-queries and results to textfile. The most simple and reliable debugging of callbacks.

Comment: SQL is fine, returns what it's supposed to return. I'll put the code on pastie, hold on.

Comment: Here's my code! http://pastie.org/1709896

Answer (score 0):

maybe your problem lies within encoding, jquery needs utf8 in the default settings, but without any code, I can only speculate...

try utf8_encode($output) instead of only returning the output...

also maybe your ajax request awaits a specific datastructure (json/xml/ etc)

Answer (score 0):

I think this link is quite useful to understand the technique. After you got the AJAX technique, you may simply change your php files which can run sql queries etc. You may show the results in that way with a simple div, very trivial css implementation would be enough. I think the hardest part is solved here:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp